# ¿Cómo hago una función para saber si el número es primo?

Tags: python

```
def es_primo(numero):
  if numero<2:
    primo=False
  for i in range(2, numero):
     if  (numero % i)== 0:
        primo=False
     else:
        primo=True
  return primo
```

Comment: Con el código que posteas, ¿recibes algún error? Indica más detalles sobre el problema y/o el código si fuera necesario.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Primero debes considerar que un **número primo** es aquel que es divisible por **1 y por sí mismo** únicamente. Por lo tanto, tiene dos (02) divisores. Partiendo de esa premisa debes contar cuántos divisores hay. Si la cantidad de divisores es mayor que 2, entonces, no es un número primo. Puedes hacer una lectura de [números primos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo) en la Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

La lógica es incorrecta como se puede comprobar si ejecutas mentalmente tu código con un  número de ejemplo que no sea primo, como por ejemplo el 4:

Este es tu código:

```
def es_primo(numero):
  if numero<2:
    primo=False
  for i in range(2, numero):
     if  (numero % i)== 0:
        primo=False
     else:
        primo=True
  return primo
```

Veamos que hace con el caso `numero=4`

- ¿Es menor que 2? No. Por tanto continúa con el bucle for
- Bucle for, primera iteración con `i=2`

  - ¿Es 4 divisible entre 2? Si --> `primo=False`
  - El `else` no se ejecuta
- Segunda iteración con `i=3`

  - ¿Es 4 divisible entre 3? No --> No se ejecuta la cláusula del if
  - Se ejecuta entonces el `else` --> `primo = True`
- Hemos terminado de iterar en el bucle, retornamos `primo` que vale `True`

Como resultado tu código nos dice que el 4 es primo

¿Ves dónde está el error?

El problema es que, una vez hemos encontrado un divisor (el 2) ya sabemos que no es primo, por tanto **no debemos seguir probando** con más divisores, y así ahorraremos tiempo. Podemos retornar inmediatamente el valor `False`

**Solo si** agotamos el bucle for sin haber encontrado ningún divisor podremos decir que era primo y retornar `True`.

Por tanto con un simple cambio ya lo tendrías:

```
def es_primo(numero):
  if numero<2:
    return False
  for i in range(2, numero):
     if  (numero % i)== 0:
        return False
  # Hemos agotado el bucle sin encontrar divisores
  return True
```

### Optimización

No es necesario recorrer todos los números entre 2 y el número. Basta recorrer hasta la raiz cuadrada del número. Si no ha aparecido un divisor menor a su raiz cuadrada tampoco aparecerá uno mayor, ya que supon que X es un divisor de N, eso implicaría que hay otro número Y tal que X*Y=N. Si X fuese mayor de la raiz cuadrada, Y tendría que ser menor y ya lo habríamos encontrado antes.

Eso permite reducir el número de iteraciones del bucle:

```
import math

def es_primo(numero):
  if numero < 2:
    return False
  for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(numero))+1):
     if  (numero % i)== 0:
        return False
  return True
```

Comment: En la librería `math` se incluye la raiz cuadrada de enteros, `isqrt`, que evita tener que trabajar con números de coma flotante.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Gracias por el aporte, pero esa función sólo está disponible a partir de la versión 3.8, asi que para que sea más universal voy a dejar la respuesta como estaba.

Answer (score 0):

Si el numero menor de 2, retornar `True`
Si el numero es 2, retornar `True`
Si el numero es par o sea `numero % 2 == 0` retornar `False`
Si el numero es impar y es divisible por cualquier numero impar, a partir de 3 hasta la mitad del mismo numero, retornar `False`.
Si el `for` logra termina sin entrar al `if`, entonces el numero es primo y ejecutará la última linea `return True`.

```
def es_primo(numero):
    if numero < 2:
        return False
    if numero == 2:
        return True
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, numero//2, 2):
        if numero % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Pruebas

```
print(es_primo(1)) # False
print(es_primo(2)) # True
print(es_primo(3)) # True
print(es_primo(8)) # False
print(es_primo(13)) # True
print(es_primo(27)) # False
print(es_primo(101)) # True
print(es_primo(113)) # True
print(es_primo(517)) # False
```