# Cantidad de números primos en python

Tags: python

Hola estoy intentando crear un programa que me muestre en pantalla los números primos desde el 2 hasta el numero que coloque ejemplo: si coloco el 10 me tiene que mostrar 2,3,5,7 pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

```
num = int(input("Escribe un numero: "))

cont=0
i=1
j=1

for i in range(2,num+1):
    for j in range(2,i):
        if (i%j==0):
            cont+=1
        if (cont==2):
            print(i)
            cont=0
```

Comment: La variable `cont` debe ponerse a cero dentro del primer `for`, antes de entrar al `for` interno. El segundo `if` debe ir a la altura del `for` interno. El `range()` interno debe  ir de `1` a 
 `i+1`.  Creo que con eso ya funcionará, aunque todo el código es muy ineficiente por hacer muchas más operaciones de las necesarias (pero eso ya es otra historia)

Comment: Gracias si funciono de esa manera y la verdad no se si sea ineficiente es la manera en la que lo pensé ya lo había hecho con while y me funciono pero no entendía por que no me funcionaba con for y claro estaba mal en todo eso gracias es que estoy practicando y soy nuevo en esto de la programación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer de una forma más directa sin recurrir a contadores:

```py
num = int(input("Escribe un numero: "))

for i in range(2, num+1):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(f"{i} es primo")
```

En el bucle interno se van probando divisores de `i` de `2` a `i-1`. Si encuentra alguno, se sale del bucle y se continua con el siguiente. Si no se encuentra ningún divisor, se acaba el bucle y se ejecuta el `else`, donde puede ser ya considerado el número como primo.

Un método más directo sería usando *compresiones de listas*:

```py
primos = [i for i in range(2, num+1) if not any(i % j == 0 for j in range(2, i))]
```

Comment: Para evitar iteraciones al cohete, puedes probar hasta la mitad del numero redondeado hacia abajo mas 1 (numero//2+1), ya que un divisor debe ser un natural y no puede ser mas grande que la mitad del numero cuyos divisores se quieren conseguir (a excepción del numero mismo).

Comment: También en [una respuesta a otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/432755/158880) dicen que se puede buscar hasta la raiz cuadrada del numero.

Comment: Nunca imagine que se podría hacer de esa manera es que estoy empezando en la programación. Además no entiendo eso del break no se que función cumpla tendré que investigar para ver como funciona eso, como ya lo había hecho con while lo hice con la comparativa de cont==2 y me funciono por eso lo estaba intentado hacer de la misma forma pero con for

Comment: No te preocupes si no entiendes algo del código. Lee la documentación, analiza mucho código de otros y prueba a hacerlo tú mismo. Con paciencia, cada vez entenderás más y cosas como el `break` te parecerán normales.

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo varias cosas mal. Utilizando tu lógica deberías tener en cuenta varias cosas:

- En cada iteración de `i` debes establecer `cont` a `0`, ya que es la variable que estás evaluando para saber si `i` es primo o no.

```
for i in range(2, num+1):
    cont = 0
```

- A la hora de evaluar `i` y `j`, aparte de comprobar que resto entre ellos es 0 deberías comprobar también que son distintos entre si

```
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            cont += 1
```

- Para comprobar si `i` tiene algún divisor no puedes comprobar que `cont` sea exactamente 2, ya que puede tener más de dos divisores. Simplemente comprueba que haya más de 0

Hasta aquí tendríamos algo así:

```
for i in range(2, num+1):
    cont = 0
    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            cont += 1
    if cont == 0:
        print(i)
```

- Como detalle te diría que en lugar de declarar un contador que vaya almacenando el número de divisores pensaras en el test como un booleano que toma el valor True si encuentra algún divisor. Lo renombraremos como `tiene_divisores`:

```
for i in range(2, num+1):
    tiene_divisores = False
    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            tiene_divisores = True
    if not tiene_divisores:
        print(i)
```

- Otro punto importante es que no es necesario que sigas comprobando cada iteración de `j` si ya ha encontrado un divisor. Piensa en ello como un `while` en lugar de un `for` que se ejecute siempre y cuando `tenga_divisores` sea `False` y `j` sea distinto de `i`:

```
    while not tiene_divisores and j != i:
        if i % j == 0:
            tiene_divisores = True
        j += 1
```

**En resumen**

```
num = int(input("Escribe un numero: "))


for i in range(2, num+1):
    tiene_divisores = False
    j = 2
    while not tiene_divisores and j != i:
        tiene_divisores = True if i % j == 0 else False
        j += 1
    if not tiene_divisores:
        print(i)
```

---

Esto se podría simplificar muchísimo más, pero lo dejo así para que entiendas la solución.

De cualquier modo, como ya te han dicho esta no es una solución demasiado eficiente, pero espero haberte explicado por qué tu lógica no te estaba funcionando

Comment: Tal como lo has puesto, cuando `j` alcanza el valor de `i` siempre será divisible por lo que se mostrarán todos los números como primos.

Comment: Cuando j alcanza i se sale del while

Comment: Gracias por la explicación estuve viendo que cometí muchos errores nunca pensé hacerlo con booleanos pero me funciono igual debería practicar mas sobre eso por que nunca he practicado los booleanos

Answer (score 0):

este codigo puede optimizarse mucho, pero te ayudará bastante:

Primero, necesitas un programa que detecte si un numero es primo o no, para ello haremos fuerza bruta realizando divisiones sucesivas entre los numeros menores al que estas evaluando. Para revisar si un numero `N` es primo por fuerza bruta, basta dividir `N` entre todos los numeros menores a la raiz cuadrada de N, la llamaremos `cota`. Aqui podemos evitar algunas iteraciones revisando primero si el numero es par (el unico primo que es par es el 2, por ello los demas pares no seran primos), y dividiendo unicamente entre impares.2

```
def es_primo(N: int) -> bool:
    """
    Verifica si el numero N es primo, y retorna True/False.
    """
    # Verificamos si es par
    if N%2==0:
        # En caso de ser par, solo cuando N es 2 se devuelve True
        return N==2
    else:
        # Fijamos el valor de cota, usamos ** porque es mas rapido que pow()
        cota = 1 + int(N**0.5)
        # Realizamos divisiones sucesivas, evitando los pares:
        for divisor in range(3,cota,2):
            # Revisamos si dividor divide a N, si eso sucede N no es primo
            if N % divisor == 0:
                return False
    # Si el codigo llega a este punto, es porque N es 1 o primo
    return N!=1
```

Luego, solo debes buscar los primos entre `N` y `M` con el siguiente codigo:

```
lista_primos = []
for iterador in range(N, M+1):
    if es_primo(iterador):
        lista_primos.append(iterador)
print(*lista>primos, sep=', ', end='.\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que la recursividad te sería mucho más eficiente:

```
    def es_primo(num, n=2):
        if num == 1 or num == 2:
            print("Es primo.")
        elif num%n != 0:
            return es_primo(num, n+1)
        else:
            print("No es primo: " + str(n) + " es divisor.")
    
    es_primo(int(input("Número a comprobar: ")))
```

Comment: Cuidado, que en python está limitado en el número de llamadas recursivas que puedes hacer. Si pruebas con `es_primo(10007)` verás que sobrepasa este límite y da error. En cuanto a eficiencia, siempre es más eficiente un bucle que una llamada recursiva. En algunos lenguajes, puede que el compilador optimize una función recursiva que se llame en ["posición _tailrec_"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)#Funciones_de_recursi%C3%B3n_de_cola) y sea igual de eficiente, pero el lenguaje python no es el caso.