# Retornar una lista de números primos con dos parametros (desde, hasta)

Tags: python

Esta función devuelve una lista con los números primos entre los valores "desde" y "hasta"
pasados como parámetro, siendo ambos inclusivos.
En caso de que alguno de los parámetros no sea de tipo entero y/o no sea mayor a cero, debe retornar nulo.
En caso de que el segundo parámetro sea mayor al primero, pero ambos mayores que cero,
debe retornar una lista vacía.
Recibe un argumento:
desde: Será el número a partir del cual se toma el rango
hasta: Será el número hasta el cual se tome el rango

```
listaPrimos = []
    esPrimo = True
    if(desde > hasta):
        return listaPrimos
    else:
        while(esPrimo):
          for i in range(desde, len(listaPrimos)):
            if desde % i == 0:
                esPrimo = False
            listaPrimos.append(i)
    return listaPrimos
```

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Buenos dias ¿Cual es su problema?

Comment: El problema es que necesito devolver una lista con los numeros primos dentro de un rango, por ejemplo (1.7), lo que se espera que retorne la función es [1,2,3,5,7]

Comment: 1 no es un número primo

Comment: La idea es que dentro de un rango de dos números, pasados como parámetros a la función, pueda devolver una lista de números primos que sea comprendida entre estos dos números que pase como parámetros.

Comment: Mi sugerencia: separa el proceso en 2 funciones. Una para determinar si un número es primo y la otra para generar la lista de primos dentro del rango dado. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cantidad de números primos en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514365/cantidad-de-n%c3%bameros-primos-en-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordenando el código obtenemos:

```
def primos(desde, hasta):
    listaPrimos = []

    if desde < 2:
        desde = 2
        
    if (desde <= hasta):
        #   Iterar de dos en dos, partiendo de impar
        for entero in range(desde, hasta + 1):
            #   Por cada entero en el rango, chequear si es primo
            for i in range(2, entero):
                if entero % i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                #   Se recorrieron todos los primos sin que
                #   ninguno sea el divisor -> un nuevo primo
                listaPrimos.append(entero)

    return listaPrimos
```

Como el 1 no es primo, nos aseguramos que `desde` sea >= 2:

```
if desde < 2:
    desde = 2
```

Y luego recorremos el rango

```
#   Iterar de dos en dos, partiendo de impar
for entero in range(desde, hasta + 1):
```

Por cada elemento en el rango verificamos si es primo o no:

```
#   Por cada entero en el rango, chequear si es primo
for i in range(2, entero):
    if entero % i == 0:
        break
```

Si el `for` termina normal (sin salir por `break`), se ejecuta el `else` que agrega el `entero` a la lista de primos:

```
else:
    #   Se recorrieron todos los primos sin que
    #   ninguno sea el divisor -> un nuevo primo
    listaPrimos.append(entero)
```

#### Demo

```
print(primos(3,20))
print(primos(1,7))
print(primos(10,9))
```

produce:

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[]    

Process finished with exit code 0
```